# updated python but pip is still in previous version

Tags: python, pip

So its a little confusing but, I wanted to install the new version of python which is 3.11.1

when I installed it, it was successful. when I went to use it in vs code, however...none of the packages I had in 3.10 were registered. but when I went to install the packages I needed, it said they were already satisfied in the 3.10 python folder.

pygame is not installed in 3.11.1
[image]

pip goes to 3.10 to say its already satisfied
[image]

what im wanting is for all my libraries and packages in 3.10 to be in 3.11

Comment: Well, you are going to have to re-install them. You really should be using virtual environments to begin with.

Comment: what is a virtual environment in this context? elaborate further as i am confused.

Comment: You may use ```python -m pip``` instead of directly using ```pip```.

Comment: is there a way where i can make pip use 3.11?by default instead of forcing it in the command?

Answer (score 0):

> [Pygame still does not run on Python 3.11](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Pygame%20Installation)

Install an older version of python such as `3.10` or `3.8`, then

Make sure to use the `-<version>` flag after the py executable like so:

```bash
py -3.11 -m pip install pygame
```

and select the correct interpreter version in VS Code as well as reloading after installing a package

Comment: is there a way i could make pip use 3.11 by default instead of specifying what version to install it as, plus pygame didnt install because
 ```python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.```

Comment: You can move the path to the Python executable and the scripts folder above the over versions in the path env var to use that one as default, as for the error: update `setuptools` and install `ez_setup`

Comment: Just looked it up and from the pygame install page: "Pygame still does not run on Python 3.11"

Comment: so add it to env vars

Comment: The path to python 3.11 should already be there, just move it up, however, once again: Pygame does not work on Python 3.11, see my edited answer